ORDER strings with LINQ Orderby
Please consider this code:
string str1 = "M"; // <---77
string str2 = "m"; // <---109

var list = new List<string>() {str1, str2};

list = list.OrderBy(a=>a).ToList();

The problem is despite m has larger ascii code but it becomes before M. Why is happening here?
What type of comarision does LINQ use for sorting and how can I change it?

FYI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-8.0

@ProgrammingLlama: thanks. I read it but what type of comarision does LINQ use for sorting and how can I change it?

You can specify an icomparer to use as a parameter to the orderby. For example a specific culture or your own.

from MS Dotnet documentation about Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>:

This method compares keys by using the default comparer Default.

from MS Dotnet documentation about Comparer<T>.Default

The Comparer<T> returned by this property uses the System.IComparable<T> generic interface (IComparable<T> in C#, IComparable(Of T) in Visual Basic) to compare two objects.

from MS Dotnet documentation about System.String:
public sealed class String : ICloneable, IComparable, IComparable<string>, IConvertible, IEquatable<string>, IParsable<string>, ISpanParsable<string>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>

from MS Dotnet documentation about String.CompareTo

This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) comparison using the current culture. For more information about word, string, and ordinal sorts, see System.Globalization.CompareOptions.

from MS Dotnet supplementary remarks about System.Globalization.CompareOptions

Word sort performs a culture-sensitive comparison of strings. Certain nonalphanumeric characters might have special weights assigned to them. For example, the hyphen ("-") might have a very small weight assigned to it so that "coop" and "co-op" appear next to each other in a sorted list.

from MS Dotnet document "How to compare strings in C#"

In addition, some Unicode characters might be equivalent to a sequence of Char instances. The following example uses the phrase "They dance in the street." in German with the "ss" (U+0073 U+0073) in one string and 'ß' (U+00DF) in another. Linguistically (in Windows), "ss" is equal to the German Esszet: 'ß' character in both the "en-US" and "de-DE" cultures.


Prior to .NET 5, the .NET globalization APIs used National Language Support (NLS) libraries. In .NET 5 and later versions, the .NET globalization APIs use International Components for Unicode (ICU) libraries, which unifies .NET's globalization behavior across all supported operating systems.

So it's clear that OrderBy doesn't compare string by unicode codepoint order, but using special rule to "culturalize" comparison.

You can use OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TKey>, IComparer<TKey>) to provide comparer other than default.
This additional question was added later, and I think someone already provided example code to make custom comparer for you.
To use other "default" string comparer, use StringComparer.
from MS Dotnet documentation about System.StringComparer
public abstract class StringComparer : System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<string>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>, System.Collections.IComparer, System.Collections.IEqualityComparer

// This example demonstrates members of the 
// System.StringComparer class.

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        // Create a list of string.
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        // Get the tr-TR (Turkish-Turkey) culture.
        CultureInfo turkish = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");

        // Get the culture that is associated with the current thread.
        CultureInfo thisCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        // Get the standard StringComparers.
        StringComparer invCmp =   StringComparer.InvariantCulture;
        StringComparer invICCmp = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
        StringComparer currCmp = StringComparer.CurrentCulture;
        StringComparer currICCmp = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
        StringComparer ordCmp = StringComparer.Ordinal;
        StringComparer ordICCmp = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

        // Create a StringComparer that uses the Turkish culture and ignores case.
        StringComparer turkICComp = StringComparer.Create(turkish, true);

        // Define three strings consisting of different versions of the letter I.
        // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I (U+0049)
        string capitalLetterI = "I";  

        // LATIN SMALL LETTER I (U+0069)
        string smallLetterI   = "i";

        // LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I (U+0131)
        string smallLetterDotlessI = "\u0131";

        // Add the three strings to the list.
        list.Add(capitalLetterI);
        list.Add(smallLetterI);
        list.Add(smallLetterDotlessI);

        // Display the original list order.
        Display(list, "The original order of the list entries...");

        // Sort the list using the invariant culture.
        list.Sort(invCmp);
        Display(list, "Invariant culture...");
        list.Sort(invICCmp);
        Display(list, "Invariant culture, ignore case...");

        // Sort the list using the current culture.
        Console.WriteLine("The current culture is \"{0}\".", thisCulture.Name);
        list.Sort(currCmp);
        Display(list, "Current culture...");
        list.Sort(currICCmp);
        Display(list, "Current culture, ignore case...");

        // Sort the list using the ordinal value of the character code points.
        list.Sort(ordCmp);
        Display(list, "Ordinal...");
        list.Sort(ordICCmp);
        Display(list, "Ordinal, ignore case...");

        // Sort the list using the Turkish culture, which treats LATIN SMALL LETTER 
        // DOTLESS I differently than LATIN SMALL LETTER I.
        list.Sort(turkICComp);
        Display(list, "Turkish culture, ignore case...");
    }

    public static void Display(List<string> lst, string title)
    {
        Char c;
        int  codePoint;
        Console.WriteLine(title);
        foreach (string s in lst)
        {
            c = s[0];
            codePoint = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x}", codePoint); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
/*
This code example produces the following results:

The original order of the list entries...
0x49
0x69
0x131

Invariant culture...
0x69
0x49
0x131

Invariant culture, ignore case...
0x49
0x69
0x131

The current culture is "en-US".
Current culture...
0x69
0x49
0x131

Current culture, ignore case...
0x49
0x69
0x131

Ordinal...
0x49
0x69
0x131

Ordinal, ignore case...
0x69
0x49
0x131

Turkish culture, ignore case...
0x131
0x49
0x69

*/

In my opinion, you would want to use StringComparer.Ordinal.

If no comparer is specified, OrderBy will obtain a comparer using Comparer<T>.Default. Ultimately, this seems to resolve GenericComparer<T>, which uses string's CompareTo method. You can look into that starting from here if you wish to take a dive in the code.
From what I've read in the documentation for StringComparer.InvariantCulture, it seems like m coming before M is the "linguistically relevant" order, so I would assume other culture-sensitive comparers for English also assume the same order.
As to how to sort it the way you want, you can specify a comparer (built-in or custom) to the OrderBy method. For example: list.OrderBy(a => a, StringComparer.InvariantCulture) (but probably not this comparer).
If your culture's way of sorting text would see M come before m then you'll either want to set the thread culture and use normal culture-sensitive sorting, or you'll want to obtain a string comparer for your culture (using en-US here as an example):
var cultureStringComparer = new CultureInfo("en-US").CompareInfo.GetStringComparer(CompareOptions.Ordinal);
list = list.OrderBy(a => a, cultureStringComparer).ToList();

If it isn't culture-specific, then I don't know of a specific comparer that will sort it in the way you want, so you'll probably need to create a custom one a little like this:
Barebones example of custom string comparer
public class CustomStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static readonly CustomStringComparer _instance = new CustomStringComparer();
    public static CustomStringComparer Instance => _instance;

    private CustomStringComparer() { }

    public int Compare (string x, string y)
    {
        if (string.Equals(x, y)) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
           
        int minLength = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < minLength; ++i)
        {
            var compareResult = ((int)x[i]).CompareTo(y[i]);
            if (compareResult != 0)
            {
                return compareResult;
            }
        }
        return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
    }
}

This is just an example based on your implied desire to compare ASCII codes. I expect it doesn't handle many cases very well, so you'll probably need to make changes to it if you want it to do exactly what you need to.
Usage:
list = list.OrderBy(a => a, CustomStringComparer.Instance).ToList();


Your CustomStringComparer : IComparer<string> isn't stable based on string length. You need to return the last compare based on either the longest or shortest string.

@Enigmativity Ah yes, I missed that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Just a quick answer, you need to implement your own IComparer<string> to get a different ordering from LINQ.
Here's a performant method:
public class CharStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string left, string right)
    {
        using (var le = left.GetEnumerator())
        {
            using (var re = right.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (le.MoveNext() && re.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (le.Current != re.Current)
                    {
                        return le.Current.CompareTo(re.Current);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return left.Length.CompareTo(right.Length);
    }
}

Now you can write:
string str1 = "M"; // <---77
string str2 = "m"; // <---109

var list = new List<string>() { str1, str2 };

list = list.OrderBy(a => a, new CharStringComparer()).ToList();

